# How to animate existing SVG element with jQuery svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have the following HTML with embedded svg:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"
        width="100px" height="100px">
    <circle id="circle" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFC600"
        cx="50" cy="50" r="10"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I simply want to use [KW jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to animate the radius to 50. I try the following, but it does not work

```
$('#container').svg();
var svg = $('#container').svg('get');
$('#circle', svg.root()).animate({svgR: 50}, 1000);
```

Am I going at this the wrong way? I am a bit lost.

Comment: You can also change radius using this code $('circle').attr('r',50);

Comment: @Chirag It needs to be animated smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a very stupid mistake. Make sure you include the jquery.svganim.js file. You will get no errors if you try to animate without it. Also, the above example can be simplified a lot:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"
        width="100px" height="100px">
    <circle id="circle" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFC600"
        cx="50" cy="50" r="10"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#circle').animate({svgR: 50}, 1000);
</script>
```